# Convergence of improper integral (Dirichlet-Abel)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I need to prove that the following integral converges:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)}{(x^2+1)(x-1)}dx$$

From Dirichlet-Abel, I know that:

If $\alpha:[a, +\infty]$ and $U:[a, +\infty]$ and:

(1): $\alpha(x) > 0$ for all $x>0$

(2): $\alpha$ is decresing

(3): $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\alpha(x)=0$

(4): Exists real $k$ and, for all $\lambda>a$: $|\int_{a}^{\lambda}U(x)dx|<k$

So,

$\int_{a}^{\infty}\alpha(x).U(x)dx$ converges

---

But I can't put $a=-\infty$ (my professor told me that), so I don't know how to use it here. In other situation, I would say that the function is even or odd (so I multiply the integral for 2 and say that $a=0$), but this is not the case, because $x-1$ is not even nor odd.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Prove that $\frac{\cos \pi/2x}{x-1}$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ and take it from there.

Comment: I think, rigorously, first you gotta split the integral into $\int_{-\infty}^a+\int_{a}^{1}+\int_{1}^{b}+\int_{b}^{+\infty}$ where $a<1<b$.

Comment: According to @HansEngler, consider $\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})/(x-1)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}(1-x))/(x-1)$ when $x\to 1$

Comment: It converges to $\tau~\big(1+e^\tau\big)$, where $\tau=-\dfrac\pi2$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Is there any theorem or something?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\left|\frac{\cos(\frac\pi2x)}{x-1}\right|=\left|\frac{\sin(\frac\pi2(1-x))}{x-1}\right|\lt\frac\pi2$. Therefore, the integrand is less than $\dfrac{\pi/2}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: And how do you know that $\dfrac{\pi/2}{x^2+1}$ converges? How do you know that $\left|\frac{\sin(\frac\pi2(1-x))}{x-1}\right|\lt\frac\pi2$ ?? Thanks

Comment: @Juan: If you don't know what the integral of $\frac1{x^2+1}$ is, you can break things up: when $|x|\le1$, use $\frac1{x^2+1}\le1$; when $|x|\gt1$ use $\frac1{x^2+1}\lt\frac1{x^2}$. I was assuming that $\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\le1$ was known.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that. I'm having troubles when I have to prove that the following integral diverges: $\int_{-4-\epsilon}^{-4+\epsilon}\frac{\cos{x}}{(x^2+3^x-4)x)}dx$

Comment: @Juan: does this have anything to do with this question, or is this a separate question?

Comment: It's the same question. That integral is part of the integral between $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Comment: @Juan: that certainly doesn't look the same. The one in the question has $1$ singularity which is canceled by $\cos(\frac\pi2x)$. The one in your comment has $3$ singularities, $0$, $1$, and $-1.97111816$, none of which are canceled by $\cos(x)$.

Comment: Oh! This was not the thread I wanted to post in. Sorry!!! Yes, here I have a different trouble, but I still don't know how you get that. For example, to prove convergence I use Dirichlet-Abel theorem but in this case I think I cannot use it because the integral is between $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and the function is not even or odd

Comment: This integral converges absolutely. There is no reason to invoke Dirichlet-Abel here. However, that test is usually used to show convergence on infinite domains of integration.

Comment: But how can you prove that? I know that $cos(\frac{\pi.x}{2})<=1$ but I can't say anything about $(x^2+1)(x-1)=x^3-x^2+x-1<x^3-x^2+x$

Comment: @Juan: Perhaps you missed the first part of the hint where it is shown that $$\left|\frac{\cos(\frac\pi2x)}{x-1}\right|\lt\frac\pi2$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21237/discussion-between-juan-and-robjohn).